# How to correctly pass the number lambdaeff to the cores using OpenMP in this Fortran code?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran

I am trying ot parallelize a code which calculates two integer numbers `nue` and `nut`; these numbers are then used to calculate another number `lambdaeff`. I can show a (stupid) MWE (the actual code is 1200 lines Monte Carlo code):

```
Do n=1, 100
 nue=int(100*rand())
 nut=int(50*rand())
 lambdaeff=lambdaeff+(nue-nut)^2
end do
```

If I parallelize the code as indicated [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/OpenMP), using a parallel `do` loop, I am not sure that the `lambdaeff` number will be passed correctly to the various cores. How can I modify the last line of the loop to pass correctly `lambdaeff` to the cores?

Comment: Do you want to use OpenMP or MPI? Please clarify, they are totally different things. And please include the code in the question.

Comment: I cannot include the code in the question, since it ia a 1200 lines Monte Carlo code, I can try to do a MWE. I want to use OpenMP.

Comment: A MWE would be useful

Comment: Do NOT use `rand()`. Certainly do not use it in any parallel code, but also avoid it in general. For Monte-Carlo you need a reliable tested random number generator. And for OpenMP you need something thread-safe.

Comment: @VladimirF Why? What's wrong with `rand()`?

Comment: There are absolutely no guarantees about the quality of the generator and it will likely not be as good as `random_number()` even-though this one is not guaranteed either - very bad for good Monte-Carlo. And it is not thread safe - OpenMP will crash or generate garbage results (and be slow too).

Comment: For example in gfortran [`RAND()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RAND.html) implements just a "simple modulo generator as provided by g77" while [`RANDOM_NUMBER`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html#RANDOM_005fNUMBER) is in gfortran implemented using a very good and fast generator and thread-safe. But nothing is guaranteed in general for other compilers. It is good to use a dedicated library.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the lambdaeff number will be passed correctly to the various cores" - I really do not understand what you are trying to say here. Do you want each thread to have the same lambdaeff?

Comment: @IanBush yes each core should have the same lambdaeff.

Comment: @IanBush even after the sum of the new term: the new lambdaeff should be known to all the cores

Comment: Please learn the difference between threads and cores, it is the former term you should be using. But to solve your problem you want a reduction - there must be a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, then you want to use a `reduction`. See here for an example: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments by @Vadimir F, @PetrH, and @Ian Bush:

- Do NOT use `rand()` as it is not thread safe; use [`random_number()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html#RANDOM_005fNUMBER) instead,
- You want to use OpenMP [`reduction`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html),
- There is a big [difference between core and thread](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-cores-and-threads-of-a-processor), please look it up (the latter term applies here).

EDIT:

> If I had a second variable `lnet=lnet-nue+nut` which should be shared by all threads like `lambdaeff` how should I modify the reduction statement?

```
program main
  use, intrinsic :: omp_lib
  implicit none
  integer :: i, tid, nthreads
  integer :: nue, nut, lambdaeff = 0, lnet = 0
  real    :: r(2)

  ! Set number of threads
  nthreads = OMP_get_max_threads()
  write (*,*) "Using ", nthreads, "thread(s)"

  !$OMP PARALLEL NUM_THREADS(nthreads) PRIVATE(tid)
  ! Who am I?
  tid = OMP_get_thread_num()

  ! Reduction do loop
  !$OMP DO REDUCTION(+:lambdaeff,lnet) PRIVATE(nue,nut,r)
  do i = 1, 100
    call random_number(r)
    nue = int(100*r(1))
    nut = int(50*r(2))
    lambdaeff = lambdaeff + (nue-nut)**2
    lnet = lnet+(nue-nut)

  end do
  !$OMP END DO

  ! lambdaeff is same for all threads
  write (*,*) tid, lambdaeff, lnet

  !$OMP END PARALLEL

end program main
```

Comment: If I had a second variable `lnet=lnet-nue+nut` which should be shared by all threads like `lambdaeff` how should I modify the reduction statement?

Comment: General syntax for reduction is: `REDUCTION(<operator>:<list,...>)`, so just add  `lnet` to parameter list.